# Python 2.7: How to make a function print an undetermined amount of strings from a tuple

Tags: python-2.7

I'm making a text-based adventure game, and would like to have a universal 'look' function that uses an algorithm to tell the player how many and what objects are in a room instead of me having to write individual descriptions for each room. So it would work roughly like this:

```
lookround(things.bedroom)
```

> You see:
>
> a bed, which is the last on the right, across from Jacob's and to the left of Steve's,
>
> and
>
> a calendar, which is on a nail driven into the wall to the left of your bed

The objects are stored in the class 'things', which has a format that organises them with the object name first, and then the description of its location, then it repeats. That way, all the function has to do is print the first two tuples, then the next two, then the next two, and so on.

So, how would I get it to print out a number of tuples which have not been spoon fed to it?

Right now, I'm trying to use this:

```
def lookround(room):
    print '''You see:'''
    for len(room) % 2:
        print ('{}, which is {},'.format(room))
```

The problems I'm having are that I'm getting a syntax error which points to the colon after len, and I'm not sure what I should put in `.format()` .
I've tried messing around with the syntax, but nothing's working.

Comment: That is not the correct syntax for a [`for` loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class room(object):
    things = ('a bed', 'to sleep in',
              'a calendar', 'to look up the date',
              'a clock', 'to wake up')

def lookround(room):
    print '''You see:'''
    for i in range(len(room.things)):
        if not (i%2):
            print ('{}, which is {},'.format(room.things[i], room.things[i+1]))
            if i != len(room.things) - 2:
                print 'and'
```

This should work with your current format. It might be a better idea to store `things` as a tuple of tuples, so you don't deal with the modulus business...

Comment: Will it work if I replace the reference to room.things on line 10 with a 2nd function argument? Also, whenever I run the function with room.things as the argument, it gives me the error ''tuple' object has no attribute 'things''.

Comment: After looking over it again, could I just replace                    .format(room.things[i], room.things[i+1])) with                       .format(room[i], room[i+1])) ?

Comment: @tank These are good questions to be asking yourself. That is kind of the nature of the design process. There are always a million ways to do something, but you must weigh the design with the requirements. The language just provides you a set of tools to design what you choose.

Comment: Thank you, for the advice and the script. Sorry for not thanking you sooner, my router bricked on me and I had to order a new one.